# Using macros in SAS SQL

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I am wondering of I can consolidate some code into one `PROC SQL` statement instead of several back-to-back `SQL` statements.

I am using macro to calculate the age of a participant at date of consent for a study, similar to what is provided [here](http://www.pauldickman.com/teaching/sas/age.php) and [here](http://www.nesug.org/proceedings/nesug01/cc/cc4022.pdf).  I tried to troubleshoot the functionality of macros, and I calculated the total weight of a baby at birth in ounces using the **%sum** macro (which works great...).  However, when trying to calculate age, the macros don't work.

*However,* if I use the macros in a new `SQL` statement, it works fine.

The code below works:

```
%macro months(somedate,birth);
intck('month',&birth,&somedate) 
         - (day(&somedate) < day(&birth))
%mend months;

%macro days(somedate,birth);
intck('day',&birth,&somedate) 
         - (day(&somedate) < day(&birth))
%mend days;

%macro sum(part1, part2);
&part1*16 + &part2
%mend sum;


**********  bringing in data from outside tables  ;
proc sql;
  create table demos as
    select      x.*,    infcondt2 as c_dt, 
                y.*,    datepart(visitdt)   as v_dt format date9. ,
                        datepart(birthdt)   as b_dt format date9. ,
                        birthweightlbs as lbs,
                        birthweightoz as oz,

                        lbs*16 + oz as tot_oz,
                        %sum(lbs,oz) as tot_oz_m

    from    enrolled as x, 
            demographics as y

    where x.center = y.center and x.id = y.id  ;
    quit;

**********  calculating age in months and in days  ;
proc sql;
create table demos2 as
select  * ,
        %months(c_dt, b_dt) as age_m ,
        %days(c_dt, b_dt) as age_d 
from demos;
quit;


**********  creating age groupings by months: 0-3 and 3-6  ;
proc sql;
create table demos3 as
select  * ,
        case
          when age_m le 3 then 1
          when age_m le 6 and age_m gt 3 then 2
          else 3
          end as age_interval
from demos2;
quit;
```

---

Is there any way to consolidate it into a single statement?  Something like:

```
proc sql;
  create table demos as
    select      x.*,    infcondt2 as c_dt, 
                y.*,    datepart(visitdt)   as v_dt format date9. ,
                        datepart(birthdt)   as b_dt format date9. ,
                        birthweightlbs as lbs,
                        birthweightoz as oz,

                        lbs*16 + oz as tot_oz,
                        %sum(lbs,oz) as tot_oz_m,
                        %months(c_dt, b_dt) as age_m,
                        %days(c_dt, b_dt) as age_d, 
                        case
                            when age_m le 3 then 1
                            when age_m le 6 and age_m gt 3 then 2
                            else 3
                            end as age_interval

    from    enrolled as x, 
            demographics as y

    where x.center = y.center and x.id = y.id  ;
    quit;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a field that was previously created in the same SQL statement, you need to use the `calculated` keyword.  IE:

```
proc sql;
select age*2 as double_Age, calculated double_age/2 as normal_age from sashelp.class;
quit;
```

Calculated is only needed when there is an actual calculation - ie, for b_Dt.  c_dt is only a rename of infcondt2, so you can use c_dt (or infcondt2) interchangeably, and cannot use CALCUALTED.

```
data test;
input dt1 :date9. dt2 :date9.;
datalines;
01JAN2010 01FEB2011
01DEC2011 03FEB2012
;;;;
run;

%macro months(somedate,birth);
intck('month',&birth,&somedate) - (day(&somedate) < day(&birth))
%mend months;

proc sql;
create table test2 as
select dt1 -1 as b_dt, dt2 as c_dt, %months(calculated b_dt, c_dt) as third
from test;
quit;
```

That said, you no longer need to adjust for day-of-month if you have 9.2 or sooner - look at the documnentation for INTCK.  There is an optional argument (in 9.3 it's called METHOD, I think 9.2 calls it something different) that allows you to force it to use a continuous month-concept rather than a discrete concept (counting first-of-the-months is discrete, for example, as the default used to be).

Also, I don't understand the point of the DAY macro - not only are DAYs integers (so you can just subtract the two numbers using normal subtraction), but why are you subtracting the day/day like in %month?  That's to correct for the part-of-month, as I just discussed, and is not needed for days (it would yield a wrong answer where somedate < birth).

Example of correct code:

```
%macro months(somedate,birth);
intck('month',&birth,&somedate) 
         - (day(&somedate) < day(&birth))
%mend months;

%macro days(somedate,birth);
intck('day',&birth,&somedate) 
         - (day(&somedate) < day(&birth))
%mend days;

%macro sum(part1, part2);
&part1*16 + &part2
%mend sum;

data enrolled;
input
id infcondt2 :date9.
;
datalines;
1 01JAN2011
2 02JAN2011
3 03MAR2011
;;;;
run;
data demographics;
input
id
birthweightlbs
birthweightoz
birthdt :datetime17.
;
datalines;
1 8 14 04MAR2011:15:13:14
2 7 13 05MAR2011:15:13:14
3 6 15 06MAR2011:15:13:14
;;;;
run;


proc sql;
  create table demos as
    select      x.*,    infcondt2 as c_dt, 
                y.*,    datepart(birthdt)   as b_dt format date9. ,
                        birthweightlbs as lbs,
                        birthweightoz as oz,
                        lbs*16 + oz as tot_oz,
                        %sum(lbs,oz) as tot_oz_m,
                        %months(c_dt, calculated b_dt) as age_m,
                        c_dt - calculated b_dt as age_d, /* %days is almost certainly wrong here */
                        case
                            when calculated age_m le 3 then 1
                            when 3 le calculated age_m le 6 then 2
                            else 3
                            end as age_interval

    from    enrolled as x, 
            demographics as y

    where x.id = y.id  ;
    quit;
```

Comment: Thanks for posting.  I've tried the example data, and it seems that the dates aren't coming out as date9.  .  I'll try to mock up some data that is representative of what I'm working with.  I thought the issue may have been just a syntax issue.  It is still strange to me that the macro for calculating total ounces works fine (without using `calculated` even) , whereas the age macros fail.

Comment: I realized the issue and made an edit.  CALCULATED is needed iff you have an actual calculation going on - ie, B_DT is not identical to its source column. C_DT and lbs/oz are identical to their source columns (just renamed), so there is no calculation going on; thus you can use either name.

If you're using 9.2 or newer, though, you should definitely try the proper INTCK syntax rather than bothering with the macros above - just not needed anymore (and the %day is almost certainly wrong).

Comment: As far as the DATE9. issue, that's not likely to be itself the problem (unless your variables are not numeric, but are character variables).  Internally they're stored as integer number of days (ie, 18546 or similar), so if you get the format wrong it's not a problem - still right calculations.  Your code does give a DATE9 variable for me when I use it for B_DT (not for C_DT unless your infcondt2 is a date9. to start with).

Comment: `%months(c_dt, calculated b_dt)` passes the text literal `'c_dt'` and `'calculated b_dt'` as parameters to the `%months()` macro, which expects numeric values.

Comment: Sorry, that's wrong, steve.  It passes the literal text, sure, but the macro then resolves to the function intck (and other things), which are fine handling the variable name c_dt as literal text.  It's not passing "c_dt" as a string variable or anything like that.

Comment: @Joe,  I went ahead and accepted as correct answer; it seems that `calculated` is what I was missing.  +1 for adding example data!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do complicated data step logic on your `proc sql` variables, the best way I know is to use `proc fcmp` to define the function instead of a macro.

e.g.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.util.Dates;
    function months(somedate, birth);
        return (intck('month',&birth,&somedate) - (day(&somedate) < day(&birth)));
    endsub;
run;

options cmplib=work.util;


proc sql;
create table demos as
select      x.*,    infcondt2 as c_dt, 
            y.*,    datepart(visitdt)   as v_dt format date9. ,
                    datepart(birthdt)   as b_dt format date9. ,
                    birthweightlbs as lbs,
                    birthweightoz as oz,

                    lbs*16 + oz as tot_oz,                        
                    months(c_dt, b_dt) as age_m,
                    case
                        when age_m le 3 then 1
                        when age_m le 6 and age_m gt 3 then 2
                        else 3
                        end as age_interval

from    enrolled as x, 
        demographics as y

where x.center = y.center and x.id = y.id  ;
quit;
```

You can use the `months()` function you created in `data` steps, `proc sql`, and in some other places too.

Comment: Although, in your case, the function is a simple one-liner, so you can even use `intck()` directly in SQL, as in:

`select intck('month',b_dt,c_dt) - (day(c_dt) < day(b_dt)) as age_m ...`

Comment: That's not necessarily a bad way to do it, but it's certainly not necessary in this particular instance; a macro would work as well.

Comment: @Joe I don't believe a macro would work. How would you send the values to the macro?

Comment: You don't send the values to the macro.  You send the variable names to the macro (ie, c_dt), which handles them fine.  The macro never knows about the values themselves, nor ever cares - that's not how macros work.